# 2D Tile / Time based collision detection

Tags: javascript, html, 2d, collision-detection, requestanimationframe

I'm currently creating a tower-defense game, based on a 2D tilemap.

The game loop is based on the HTML5-API requestAnimationFrame, therefore I'm using a time based animation.

Now, the problem is, how could I check effectively for collisions? If the delta is too high, the bullet could jump behind an enemy without ever triggering a collision.
Each, the bullet and the enemy, can have different movement speeds.

The only possible solution I found until now would be to implement a "Fixed Time Step Physics" which feels kinda hacky. Is there any other solution?

I guess some keywords / algorithms which fits this thematic would already help a lot!

Comment: The way I can think of is to draw a line that follows the bullets trajectory. I.E set the line's vector to be the bullets `lastPosition` to the bullets `currentPosition` each update cycle, test this line segment each update for collision/s along its path

Comment: @MatthewPigram I already thought about similar ways, but wouldn't that only work if the target doesn't move?

Comment: no because you are checking each frame along a new line for collisions

Comment: @MatthewPigram but each frame doesn't have to be called at a fixed interval. Regardless of this, I made a simple demonstration of the problem with this method. Look here: http://imgur.com/yJih1po

Comment: you have just demonstrated in the image how to solve this problem, draw a line for your target too! If both lines intersect then they have collided!

Comment: @MatthewPigram no he is right. You only have the starting and end position of both. It could be, that the 2 lines intersect at almost the end of one line, and the beginning of the other. In reality the bullet was not there anymore, when the object reached the point of intersection. But if the delta is not to big no user would see this difference. So it is a good approach. If you want to do that realistic it will take a lot of time to calculate. You have to find a balance between performance and precision.

Comment: @Lizzaran92 did any of the answers solve your problem? Or did you find another solution? If something is working for you please mark the right answer. If you found something else post it as an answer and accept it. If you stil have the same problem update your question and tell us what you have tryed.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line that follows the bullets trajectory during each update cycle. Also draw a line for any targets that might be moving using the same method, if the lines intersect then a collision has occurred (also check stationary targets).

i.e. set the line's vector to be the bullets `lastPosition` to the bullets `currentPosition` each update cycle, test this line segment each update for collision/s along its path.

Comment: Didn't saw this answer, please see my comment under my question.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Matthew Pigram's answer:

Besides drawing lines [as illustrated by Lizzaran92](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhwOb.jpg) and testing for intersection, you need to calculate the "**time**" of intersection within that frame to avoid false collisions.

For example, given both lines are going at a linear speed, if line A intersects at 50% of it's line and line B intersects at 20%, then it's likely they never collided. You can make a **threshold**, like within 10% of each other to signal a collision.

Comment: yes, which is basically what the "lines" are doing, they are acting as a threshold, really it is very difficult to detect a collision between 2 very fast moving objects efficiently. If movement speed is accelerating/decelerating at a constant rate you can figure out the point in time each will collide and use that.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are pointing in the right direction. You can use the line intersection approach. In most cases it is enaugh, as the difference between this "wrong collisions" and a real collision are to small to notice. But if you see that it doesn't seem realistic enaught. you can use the intersection point.

You have 2 objects, there speed, the starting and the endpoint of both. With this informations you can:

1. Calculate the point of intersection.
2. Calculate the distance between your startpoint and the point of intersection (d² = (x1 - x2)²  +
   (y1 - y2)²).
3. Divide it by your speed and you have got the time, when
       it reaches the intersection point.
4. Do the same for the other object.
5. Compare the 2 times, or better build the difference and use a
       tolerance (cause the objects also have a size, which you ignore in
       the calculation):

> If the difference is smaller then your tolerance a collision
>   happened.

Notice, that this could be bad for performance, so use it only if it is really necessary!